# Dynamically add rows to Google Spreadsheet with Python

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-data-api

Perhaps I didn't do the right search, but I was unable to find this answer and I'm looking for the answer with Python 2.7

I'm using the Google Data API to write data to my spreadsheet. That is nothing special, just a call to `updatecell`

However, I'm writing a lot of rows and I keep running into the upper limit of empty rows within the spreadsheet.

Is there a way for me to dynamically add rows to the spreadsheet with code? So far, I've just been adding the rows manually when I'm about to run out :(

Comment: Is there any reason why you must do this in Google Spreadsheet? (ie is Excel acceptable?)

Comment: I need to quickly share these sheets out with other people, in near real-time, and Google spreadsheets is perfect for that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried InsertRow? Something like:

```
myDict = {'col1': 'abc', 'col2':'mytest'}
entry = gd_client.InsertRow(myDict, spreadSheetKey, workSheetKey)
```

If that doesn't work, then [python-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-google-spreadsheet) might be worth looking into.